# Should the VS11 templates fail the WinRT App Certification Kit?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-runtime, app-certification-kit, wack

I'm running the Windows 8 Consumer Preview with Visual Studio 11 Beta installed.

When I create a new WinRT/Metro application, compile it and run the App Certification Kit on this blank application, it already fails because of calls to `GetModuleFileNameW`, `GetModuleHandleW`, `LoadLibraryExW`, `LoadLibraryW` and `lstrlenA`.

I've searched the entire source tree for these calls, but cannot find them. This leads me to believe they're to be found in the libraries imported by the template project.

I could not find any statement as to whether this is an issue of the Visual Studio Beta, App Certification Kit or whether I have to take some action myself. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are, you are analyzing a Debug build of your Metro style application.  Make sure to build and deploy with Release settings before running the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK).

If you attempt to run WACK on a Debug build, other tests should also fail, including the "Debug App check" test that should inform you that "the binary [image name] is built in debug mode"  and that "the App should not install any debug binaries."

With the default build configurations, the "Opt into Windows security features" should also fail because SafeSEH is not enabled in debug builds.